# Multiple fields in the where clause of a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django

Mutliple fields in the where clause of a QuerySet

```
qs_new = model_obj.objects.all()
```

Comment: plz provide some more information...

Comment: i want to add where clause in query
like:
where ('col_name' ='value','col_name2'='value2',...)

Comment: Please formulate you questions better. From your comment it seems that you're passing values, then somehow (in later comments) your values became dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter()`to define a `WHERE` clause for your query:

```
qs_new = model_obj.objects.filter(...)
```

The [QuerySet documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) describes various ways in which you can combine conditions and filters.

Comment: for k in model_k_j:
                   
where_con = where_con  +  k  + "=" + '"' + model_k_j[k] + '"'  +  ','



model_obj.objects.filter(where_con)




getting error:


  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1024, in add_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @AshishSaxena: that's not how it works, `filter()` expects parameters, not a string. You can see examples in the documentation where they combine multiple conditions to filter on.

Comment: how can i pass multiple parameters????????

Answer (score 0):

```
qs_new = model_obj.objects.filter(col_name='value', col_name2='value2')
```

Comment: for k in model_k_j:
                   
where_con = where_con  +  k  + "=" + '"' + model_k_j[k] + '"'  +  ','



model_obj.objects.filter(where_con)




getting error:


  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1024, in add_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: My code suppose that you will pass exact values NOT dictonary!

Answer (score 0):

filters_con = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
model_name.objects.filter(**filters_con)

it is working fine for me.